# GROUP BY only rows with a certain condition and date

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a basic table in my database that has a simple transactions history such as depositing money to an account, withdrawing money, and having money refunded.  Each entry has a date associated with it.

I have a php page that displays this transactional information row by row and it looks great.  However, **is there a way within the mySQL query that I can "collapse" all "refunded" money transactions into groupings by day?**  It's quite easy to do a GROUP_BY on the transaction type but I only want to group by on if the transaction_type is of type "refund" and those refunds happened on the same day.  Thanks!

My Current Example Table:
Jan 3, Deposit, $100
Jan 3, Deposit, $200
Jan 2, Withdraw, $50
Jan 2, Refund, $100
Jan 2, Refund, $100
Jan 2, Deposit, $200
Jan 2, Refund, $100
Jan 1, Deposit, $100

How I would like the data to display
Jan 3, Deposit, $100
Jan 3, Deposit, $200
Jan 2, Withdraw, $50
Jan 2, Refund, $300  *< this row has collapsed all Refunds for Jan 2nd into 1 row*
Jan 2, Deposit, $200
Jan 1, Deposit, $100

The current SQL is something like:

SELECT transaction_date, transaction_type, transaction_amount
FROM transaction_history
WHERE customer_id = $customer_id
ORDER BY transaction_date DESC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

give this a try,

```
SELECT  transaction_date, transaction_type, SUM(transaction_amount)
FROM    TableName
-- WHERE customer_id = $customer_id
GROUP   BY transaction_date, 
           CASE WHEN transaction_type = 'refund' THEN 1 ELSE RAND() END
ORDER   BY transaction_date DESC
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcce2/3)

Comment: Better to use `id` (if such a column exists) than `rand()`, yes? Also, you need to group by date as well

Comment: @Blorgbeard yep if `id` is unique then i agree `:)` oh, forgot to add the date in the group by.

Comment: I tweaked your fiddle to handle refunds on different days: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a262e/1

Comment: Thanks!  I'm just going to give it a try now.  By the way each transaction does have a unique ID which is auto incremented so I supposed I could also ORDER BY the id.

Comment: Guys like you make the internet awesome.  Thanks for helping me!