# Group only certain rows with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

**SCHEMA**

I have the following set-up in MySQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id SERIAL,
  name VARCHAR(100),
  group_id INT,
  price DECIMAL(10,2),
  KEY items_group_id_idx (group_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

INSERT INTO items VALUES 
(1, 'Item A', NULL, 10),
(2, 'Item B', NULL, 20),
(3, 'Item C', NULL, 30),
(4, 'Item D', 1,    40),
(5, 'Item E', 2,    50),
(6, 'Item F', 2,    60),
(7, 'Item G', 2,    70);
```

**PROBLEM**

> I need to select:
>
> - **All** items with `group_id` that has `NULL` value, **and**
> - **One** item from each group identified by `group_id` having the **lowest** price.

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

```
+----+--------+----------+-------+
| id | name   | group_id | price |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 | Item A |     NULL | 10.00 | 
|  2 | Item B |     NULL | 20.00 | 
|  3 | Item C |     NULL | 30.00 | 
|  4 | Item D |        1 | 40.00 | 
|  5 | Item E |        2 | 50.00 | 
+----+--------+----------+-------+
```

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION 1:** Two queries with `UNION ALL`

```
SELECT id, name, group_id, price FROM items
WHERE group_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, MIN(price) FROM items
WHERE group_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY group_id;

/* EXPLAIN */
+----+--------------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type  | table      | type | possible_keys      | key                | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY      | items      | ref  | items_group_id_idx | items_group_id_idx | 5       | const |    3 | Using where                                  | 
|  2 | UNION        | items      | ALL  | items_group_id_idx | NULL               | NULL    | NULL  |    7 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort | 
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2> | ALL  | NULL               | NULL               | NULL    | NULL  | NULL |                                              | 
+----+--------------+------------+------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

However it is undesirable to have two queries since there will be more complex condition in `WHERE` clause and I would need to sort the final results.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION 2:** `GROUP BY` on expression ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18883400/3549014))

```
SELECT id, name, group_id, MIN(price) FROM items
GROUP BY CASE WHEN group_id IS NOT NULL THEN group_id ELSE RAND() END;

/* EXPLAIN */
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | items | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |    7 | Using temporary; Using filesort | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+---------------------------------+
```

Solution 2 seems to be faster and simple to use but I'm wondering whether there is a better approach in terms of performance.

**UPDATE**:

According to documentation referenced by [@axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010981/group-only-certain-rows-with-group-by/36011093?noredirect=1#comment59674237_36010981), this query is illegal in SQL92 and earlier and may work in MySQL only.

Comment: *"One item from each group ..."* -- this is **not** a job for `GROUP BY`.

Comment: @axiac, can you please explain?

Comment: `GROUP BY` **generates** one row in the result set from each group. It does not select a row from the group. You can use `MIN(price)` to get the lowest price but there is no link between it and the row that contains the lowest price. There can be even two or more rows having that price. Using `GROUP BY` there is no way to get the entire row that has the lowest price. Read more about [how MySQL handles `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/4265352) for a solution to your problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get records with max value for each group of grouped SQL results](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12102200/get-records-with-max-value-for-each-group-of-grouped-sql-results)

Comment: Same method as your 2nd query but wiht lower chance of collisions `SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY price),',',1), MIN(price) FROM items
GROUP BY IFNULL(group_id,UUID())
ORDER BY id`

Comment: I used the GROUP_CONCAT trick to make sure you always get the name with the lower price,in your query it is not guaranteed.

Comment: @axiac, thank you for excellent description and the reference to the documentation and your answer to somewhat similar question. Although I disagree that my question is duplicate because I'm not just looking to aggregate results, I also need do it conditionally.

Comment: The `GROUP_CONCAT()` trick proposed by @Mihai should also work but it produces bloated queries, difficult to read and understand especially when there are many fields that needs to be retrieved from the table. It also has the disadvantage that for each field you have to carefully choose a delimiter to be able to split the string returned by `GROUP_CONCAT()`. For some fields (that contain user-input data) it could be impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/3549014) by [@axiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac), better solution in terms of compatibility and performance is shown below.

It is also explained in [SQL Antipatterns book, Chapter 15: Ambiguous Groups](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356557).

To improve performance, combined index is also added for `(group_id, price, id)`.

> **SOLUTION**

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, a.group_id, a.price
FROM items a
LEFT JOIN items b 
ON a.group_id = b.group_id 
AND (a.price > b.price OR (a.price = b.price and a.id > b.id))
WHERE b.price is NULL;
```

See [explanation on how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090544/3549014) for more details.

By accident as a side-effect this query works in my case where I needed to include **ALL** records with `group_id` equals to `NULL` **AND** **one** item from each group with the lowest price.

> **RESULT**

```
+----+--------+----------+-------+
| id | name   | group_id | price |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 | Item A |     NULL | 10.00 | 
|  2 | Item B |     NULL | 20.00 | 
|  3 | Item C |     NULL | 30.00 | 
|  4 | Item D |        1 | 40.00 | 
|  5 | Item E |        2 | 50.00 | 
+----+--------+----------+-------+
```

> **EXPLAIN**

```
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                 | key                | key_len | ref                        | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL  | NULL                          | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                       |    7 |                          | 
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ref  | PRIMARY,id,items_group_id_idx | items_group_id_idx | 5       | agi_development.a.group_id |    1 | Using where; Using index | 
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------+--------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+--------------------------+
```

Comment: And now add those "more complex conditions in WHERE" you were talking about :-)

Comment: @dnoeth, that should be irrelevant as those conditions would need to be applied to every solution proposed here. I wanted to avoid `UNION ALL` to avoid applying the same complex condition twice.

Comment: Not in my solution :) You still must apply the same conditions on both `items a` and `items b`, e.g. try to filter for a `minimum price > 50`

Comment: @dnoeth, your solution is smart, I like `-id` part. But I could use `WHERE b.price is NULL AND a.price > 30` once and it works fine.

Comment: Try `WHERE b.price is NULL AND a.price > 50`

Comment: @dnoeth, that gives me 0 rows since I have no items with prices above 50, which is correct.

Comment: This is just an example ("find the minimum price over 50") because there are no other columns, but if you have conditions on other columns you must repeat them.

Comment: @dnoeth, there is probably a misunderstanding, but I disagree. I can apply further conditions to table `a` only and that works fine, there is no need to repeat that clause for table `b` which is only there to find items with lowest price.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `where` conditions:

<kbd>**[`SQLFiddle Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c0a85/3)**</kbd>

```
select t.*
from t
where t.group_id is null or
      t.price = (select min(t2.price)
                 from t t2
                 where t2.group_id = t.group_id
                );
```

Note that this returns all rows with the minimum price, if there is  more than one for a given group.

EDIT:

I believe the following fixes the problem of multiple rows:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.group_id is null or
      t.id = (select t2.id
              from t t2
              where t2.group_id = t.group_id
              order by t2.price asc
              limit 1
             );
```

Unfortunately, SQL Fiddle is not working for me right now, so I cannot test it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but your query returns two rows when `group_id` and `price` are the same, see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2c179/1

Comment: @Gyrocode.com . . . That is exactly what the "Note" says.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, your second query works fine now with duplicate prices within the same group. However when outputs from `EXPLAIN` are compared, seems that the query in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36013983/3549014) is better in terms of performance.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I don't have the real data yet but strangely the timings on your query is slightly better and `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'last_query_cost'` returns `0` where my query returns `21`. Not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

If `group_id` is always a positive value you can simplify it without `GUID`/`RAND`:

```
SELECT id, name, min(price) FROM items
GROUP BY COALESCE(group_id, -id); -- id is already unique
```

But both queries will **not** return a correct result if you change the order of Inserts, I'll add a Fiddle when it's working again...

Gordon's query should work as expected or you use an old trick to get another column for `MIN`: *piggybacking*.

You concat multiple columns as fixed length string, `MIN` column as #1 and apply the `MIN` on this string. In the next step you extract the columns again using matching `SUBSTRING`:

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN grp > 0 THEN grp ELSE NULL END AS group_id
   ,CAST(SUBSTRING(x FROM 1 FOR 13) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS price
   ,SUBSTRING(x FROM 24) AS NAME
FROM
 (
   SELECT COALESCE(group_id, -id) AS grp
      -- results in a string like this
      -- '        50.00         5Item E'
      ,MIN(LPAD(CAST(price AS VARCHAR(13)),13) 
           || LPAD(CAST(id AS VARCHAR(10)),10)
           || NAME) AS x
   FROM items
   GROUP BY grp
 ) AS dt;
```

Comment: See [MySQL Handling of `GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) and [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36010981/group-only-certain-rows-with-group-by/36013983#comment59674237_36010981). Although your first query works and somewhat simpler than my attempt #2, it's not 100% correct and could only work in MySQL. Your second query is too complex for such task.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com: I wrote "But both queries will not return a correct result" :) Regarding "complexity", it's just a single table access vs. a self-join based on non-equality. Btw, in almost every other DBMS this would be a simple task for `ROW_NUMBER`.